# WOL wakes up the computer immediately after suspend

Tags: networking, suspend

I am after waking up the computer when any user on the network wants to access some of its files. ( nas role ). I did the following

- Using ethtool I checked that the nic allows WOL.
- I activate WOL so it wakes up to packages addressed only to it. ( u option on ethtool )
- I put the computer to sleep with systemcnt -suspend.

And then it immediately wakes up after it goes down.

If I don't activate WOL or if I do but remove the ethernet cable it stays asleep.
I made sure there are no other computers on the network.

It works as intended on windows.

Thanks